# Appcelerator CKeditor android WebView

Tags: webview, ckeditor, appcelerator, titanium-android

I'm trying to use the ckeditor in my app via WebView on android.

On iOS the ckeditor appear prefectly, but on android I have this error:

```
I/TiWebChromeClient.console: (main) [49519,49519] Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined (4466:file:///android_asset/Resources/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js)
```

In the ckeditor documentation appear [this](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basepath) but it doesn't work anyway.

I'm thinking if it can be an error of Titanium, because on iOS all works perfectly.

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
        var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/lib/ckeditor/';
        window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH='/lib/ckeditor/'; 
    </script>
    <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sample.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body id="main">

    <div class="adjoined-bottom">
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-width-100">
                <div id="editor">
                    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
                    <p>I'm an instance of <a href="http://ckeditor.com">CKEditor</a>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        initSample();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The fact that it works on iOS doesn't mean it will work on Android - Titanium gives native webview component - and the behavior for the webview in iOS might be different from the one in Android. Try checking in Android browser app if you can load the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium supports CKEDITOR.

ckeditor.js calls config.js, styles.js and so on. In the html file, provide path to those missing dependency files.

1] **Include the dependency files for ckeditor**

```
    <script src="lib/javascript/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/javascript/ckeditor/config.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/javascript/ckeditor/styles.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/javascript/ckeditor/lang/en-gb.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/javascript/ckeditor/plugins/panelbutton/plugin.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/javascript/ckeditor/plugins/colorbutton/plugin.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/javascript/ckeditor/plugins/colorbutton/lang/en.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/javascript/ckeditor/plugins/colorbutton/lang/en-gb.js"></script>
```

2] **For mobile application ckeditor isCompatible has to be set.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;
</script>
```

CKEDITOR.basepath setting is not required for the mobile application.